# I/flutter (14318): NoSuchMethodError: Class 'FirebaseUser' has no instance getter 'firstname'

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I am trying to update the user profile of users of app I am building. The users information is stored in firebase, the app is coded in dart running on android.

I have tried implementing example from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users website.

```
 51   createUser() {
 52     if (checkFields()) {
 53       //Perform Login
 54       var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
 55       FirebaseAuth.instance
 56           .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)
 57           .then((user) {
 58             var  userUpdateInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();
 59             user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo)
                    .then((user) {
 60                   userUpdateInfo.displayName = _Firstname;
 61                   FirebaseAuth.instance
                                  .currentUser()
                                  .then((user)  {
                                    UserManagement().storeNewuser(user, context);
 62                               })
                                  .catchError((e) {print(e);});
 63                 })
                    .catchError((e) {
 64                   print(e);
 65                 });
 66                 //UserManagement().storeNewuser(user, context);
 67                 Navigator.of(context).pop();
 68                 Navigator.of(context)
                             .pushReplacementNamed('/landingpage');
 69           })
              .catchError((e) {
 70             print("ivlvvliyviv");
 71           });
 72     }
 73   }
```

The app runs smoothly without does not crushing but when the user updates the firstname but it is not changed on firebase, line 60 was suppose to update the firstname field on firebase, and this is where I am adding my firstname field

```
Firestore.instance
         .collection('/users')
         .add({ 
           'email': user.email, 
           'uid': user.uid, 
           'firstname': user.firstname,
```

Comment: once created  - you simply want to update user - `displayName` ?

Comment: `'firstname': user.firstname` this will never work - Firebase User has no such Field.

Comment: yes i want to update user displayname, how do i go about that

Comment: I Added an Answer on updating - `User - displayName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Order to Update Firebase `User` - `displayName`. You need to make few changes in your Code.

Make - `var  userUpdateInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();` state variable outside your `.then` Function.  & then Call `user.updateProfile`.

or

Edit Your Create User code As Below:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password)
      .then((user) {
    var  userUpdateInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();
    userUpdateInfo.displayName = _Firstname;  // Pass the value you want as displayName
    user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo).then((val){  // will Update the User at Firebase Auth
      print('User Display Name Updated.');
    });
  });
```

Comment: am bit confused on how state variables work, and state variable outside my .then function, what do you mean?

Comment: Its ok  - you can Ignore that Point & add - `var  userUpdateInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();`before - `userUpdateInfo.displayName = _Firstname;` I will update the answer. let me know if you have issue in this.

Comment: yes i have an isssue, it's still not adding that field of first name on my firebase database

Comment: That is Separate issue - Update you Question  - Please note Firebase Auth User & User you Manually Save at database is different.

Comment: Firebase Auth User don't have any firstname field , it Only Has displayName